# Removing redundant linear constraints using Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, gaussian-elimination

I have a set of linear constraints in the form of $c_i x \ge d_i$ and I need to identify if an additional constraint is redundant with respect of the previously mentioned set.

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48774/eliminating-redundant-linear-constraints) I found a similar question, however it is not clear to me how to use Gaussian elimination to identify the redundant constraint.

Do you have any hints on this?

Comment: I'm not sure but you can find the rank of $C$ (of $Cx\geq d$) and then append the new constraint at the bottom of $C$ to form $C^*$ and find the rank of $C^*x\geq d^*$. Rank can be found by RREF which is esentially Gauss Elimination.

Comment: Actually, I think the link is better, since I don't want to copy someone else's question without his/her permission.

Comment: amWhy: Sure, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

See my [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69662/detection-of-redundant-constraints/69667#69667) to this MO question.

Comment: Hi, this is what I am currently doing. However I am writing a piece of software that "frequently" invokes the constraint detection and I found that solving a linear problem is slow and can get stuck in lots of iterations while finding the optimal solution (which happens a lot with higher dimensions).

Comment: I was hoping that being that the Simplex method is based on Gauss Elimination, maybe there was a simplified version of it to remove redundant constraints...

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in reading about "pruning constraints" which is discussed in chapter 11 (entitled "Analytic center cutting plane-method") of Vandenberghe's [236c notes](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236c.html).  See slide 11-12 ("pruning constraints").